# Untrusted templates in Python - what is a safe library to use?

Tags: python, email, templates

I am building a library that will be used in several Python applications. It get multilingual e-mail templates from an RMDBS, and then variable replacement will be performed on the template in Python before the e-mail is sent.

In addition to variable replacement, I need the template library to support if, elif, and for statements in the templates.

I use Mako for most my projects, and also looked at Tempita as it doesn't provide a lot of features I don't need.

The concern I have is untrusted code execution - can someone point me at a template solution for Python that either does not support code execution, or will allow me to disable it?

Comment: Maybe I should do away with the if/elif/for requirements and just use string.Template. That would be fast, require no extra libs, and meet my safety requirements.

Comment: maybe you could write a very thin wrapper around string.Template to allow the conditional statements?

Comment: What I decided to do is to create a mapper() function to bind an Object to a MailTemplate Object. When mapper is called, I define which  properties of the Object can be used in the variable replacement stage during template compilation. This way, if I need conditional or looping logic, I just use @property def in my Object and then I can use the string returned from that property def and shove it into the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/):

> For that reason, it’s impossible to call Python code directly within Django templates. All “programming” is fundamentally limited to the scope of what template tags can do. It is possible to write custom template tags that do arbitrary things, but the **out-of-the-box Django template tags intentionally do not allow for arbitrary Python code execution.**

Give [Django templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/contents/) a try. It's a little tricky to set up outside of a Django app -- something to do with `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, search around -- but may be trusted.

Comment: Thanks, that does meet my requirement for disabling code execution. However, I am trying to keep this lib simple and I fear introducing some libraries designed for Django would run counter to that.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/)? It's pretty much what you're talking about, and it's a great mix of powerful while keeping things simple and not giving the designer *too* much power. :)

If you've used Django's template system, it's very similar (if not based off of?) Jinja.

Comment: Jinja's syntax is actually based on that of Django's templates, not the other way around.