# Mako templates and security

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

I have an idea to put the templates in the database, and offer the possibility for the designer to edit the templates direct from CMS panel. But what is haunted me is the security question. How could it be any secure if we have ability to put python commands directly in the templates. If I have something like this in a mako template:

```
<%!
import os

os.system('rm /var/www/env/harmless.txt')
%>
```

it will performed successful and harmless.txt will be removed. Should I find for another template engine except Mako or could I somehow configure Mako to prevent harmful code injection? On the other hand, some python commands incredibly helpful used in templates, inline **if statement** for example.

Comment: I'm not too woried about that, if the people are running their own cms. why would they try to do harm? If you're scared about security, just run python in a sandbox then.

Comment: You can eliminate the problem entirely by using a javascript templating system and have all the rendering (and code execution) performed on the client side.  EJS and Teacup are each good, although teacup is based on coffeescript which adds an extra level of complexity if you are just using straight JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have their own separated instance of a CMS it doesn't matter like Loic points out. But if they are in some shared environment it is best to use another template engine. The question [Untrusted templates in Python - what is a safe library to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716869/untrusted-templates-in-python-what-is-a-safe-library-to-use) recommends [Django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/contents/) and [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/).

Comment: Yet, the mako engine has a preprocessor feature now that I think about it. You could preprocess the template to remove anything you don't want.

Comment: "You don't want" sounds like managing a blacklist which is never a good idea in security. Better use something already save if possible. But yes would be a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is still a possibility to do what you want. The mako engine lets you add a preprocessor to the template. I can't say for sure as I can test at the moment, but you could have something like this:

Here: http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#mako.template.Template.params.preprocessor

```
def removeImports(source):
    # remove whatever you don't want inside the template
    return new_source

tpl = Template(...., preprocessor=removeImports)
```

If you're using a framework like `pyramid` you can make it a new renderer to do that for you on all templates.

As a security concern, if you want to got that way as Mako is a terribly good engine in my own opinion. You should do a good set of test case on your preprocessor. I'm pretty sure that imports can be achieved inside inline python `<% %>`. Actually `imports` can be achieved almost anywhere inside the template as you can use inline python almost everywhere.

So if you're conerned about running python in a template, you can consider other templates such as Chameleon, Jinja2 ...